# Search box in my website which searches within the page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a search box which searches within my website . I dont want to add any external search engine. A javascript code would be helpful. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

try this in HTML :

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="31"
     maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
    <input type="radio" name="sitesearch" value="" />
    The Web
    <input type="radio" name="sitesearch"
     value="yoursite.com" checked />My site name here
</form>
```